# Ads not displaying with Admob PhoneGap Plugin

Tags: android, git, cordova

I have an Android application build with PhoneGap 3.4.

The plugin I am running is: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob.git

The installation instructions are:

````
A simplified method (tested on Cordova 3.4.0)

1. Install the Google Play Services plugin:
```cordova plugin add https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/google-play-services.git```
2. Install _this_ plugin:
```cordova plugin add https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob.git```
````

The directions for displaying the Ads are:

```
##Using the Plugin:

There are 3 calls needed to get AdMob Ads:

1. `createBannerView`

   Takes in a object containing a publisherId and adSize, as well as success
   and failure callbacks.  An example call is provided below:

        window.plugins.AdMob.createBannerView(
             {
               'publisherId': 'INSERT_YOUR_PUBLISHER_ID_HERE',
               'adSize': window.plugins.AdMob.AD_SIZE.BANNER
             },
             successCallback,
             failureCallback
         );

2. `requestAd`

   Takes in an object containing an optional testing flag, and an optional
   list of extras.  This method should only be invoked once createBannerView
   has invoked successCallback.  An example call is provided below:

         window.plugins.AdMob.requestAd(
             {
               'isTesting': false,
               'extras': {
                 'color_bg': 'AAAAFF',
                 'color_bg_top': 'FFFFFF',
                 'color_border': 'FFFFFF',
                 'color_link': '000080',
                 'color_text': '808080',
                 'color_url': '008000'
               },
             },
             successCallback,
             failureCallback
         );


3. `showAd`

   Show or hide the Ad.
```

This method should only be invoked once createBannerView has invoked successCallback.
       An example call is provided below:
                window.plugins.AdMob.showAd( 
                 true,
                 successCallback,
                 failureCallback
             );
And here is my attempt:

```
   function onLoad(){
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
function onDeviceReady() {
    if(window.plugins && window.plugins.AdMob) {
        var admob_android_key = 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        var adId = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') >=0) ? admob_android_key : admob_ios_key;
        var am = window.plugins.Admob;

        am.createBannerView(
        {
            'publisherId': adId,
            'adSize': am.AD_SIZE.BANNER,
            'bannerAtTop': false
        },
        function() {
            am.requestAd(
            { 'isTesting':false },
            function(){
                am.showAd( true );
            },
            function(){ alert('failed to request ad'); }
            );
        },
        function(){ alert('failed to create banner view'); }
        );
    } else {
        alert('AdMob plugin not available/ready.');
    }
}
```

Any idea where I am going wrong with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You copy-pasted several things from the cordova plugin readme and want somebody to combine them for you in a working example?

Comment: Okay, I updated the example. But nothing happens. I think the syntax is correct, and the Readme said this should work.

Answer (score 0):

what you pasted is too complex

there are several to show ad right.
1.install ,just add this in your phonegap build config

```
<gap:plugin name="com.admob.plugin" version="1.0.0" source="plugins.cordova.io"/>
```

2.config admob

```
admob.showBannerAbsolute(admob.BannerSize.BANNER,0,70);
```

3.show admob ad when you want.

```
admob.showBanner(admob.BannerSize.BANNER,admob.Position.TOP_APP);
```

that is all.